# Restore .bak trouble

Tags: sql-server, restore, database-restore

I'm trying to restore the database. The customer uploaded a .bak file for me, but every time I try to restore the database, I get this error:

> Logical file 'master' is not part of database 'my_db'.
> Use RESTORE FILELISTONLY to list the logical file names.

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvwS8.png)

I tried these commands

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY 
FROM DISK = 'D:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.\MSSQL\Backup\xxx_backup.BAK'
```

Result is `master` and `mastlog`.

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ljcC.png)

What I had when I wanted to restore the db, I still get the error message logical file 'master' is not part of database name.

Guys please help me.

Actually, I'm only concerned with one specific database that contains essential data for me

This is a backup that has multiple backupsets on the media. Is there a way to restore only one specific one? The `.bak` file contains a backup of all db per instance, which is approximately eight databases.

Comment: Hmm, the backup seems to contain master database, which usually shouldn't contain any user data. Are you sure this is correct?  If you use SQL Server management studio you should be able to see which databases it contains and select the one you're interested in.

Comment: In the management studio I can see a specific database, but if I select one, I get an error with a missing master file.

Comment: Pls attach which script it actually generates. Probably you're trying to restore over master db which is a bad idea

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Logical file 'master' is not part of database 'XXX'. Use RESTORE FILELISTONLY to list the logical file names. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

Comment: The .bak file is backup of all databases including master, but the error could be mdf and ldf files?

Comment: Please show the result of `RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK...` that will tell you which backupset you need. You specify the backupset number in the main `RESTORE` using `FILE = numberHere`

Comment: I cant copy image here but here is results:
NULL NULL 1 NULL 1 1 2  master 
NULL NULL 1 NULL 1 2 2  XXX_db
NULL NULL 1 NULL 1 3 2  YYY_db
NULL NULL 1 NULL 1 4 2  XY_db
NULL NULL 1 NULL 1 5 2  YX_db
NULL NULL 1 NULL 1 6 2  YXY_db
NULL NULL 1 NULL 1 7 2          Z_db

Comment: you can [edit] and paste it into your question as a table https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support. You want column `Position`, so if you want to restore database `YYY_db` for example, then you would use `WITH FILE = 2`